# How to combine jpeg frames with uncompressed mono audio into an h264 stream or any other format processed by web browsers out of the box?

Tags: audio, video-streaming, jpeg, h.264, esp32

So I have an esp32 which captures images and sound. The `esp32-camera` library already returns the jpeg encoded buffer. The audio however is uncompressed and is just a digital representation of signal strength at high sample rate.

I use esp32 to host a webpage which contains `<image>` element and a JavaScript snippet, which constantly sends GET requests to a branching url for image data and updates the element. This approach is not very good, especially that now I've added audio capabilities to the circuit.

I'm curious if it would be possible to combine jpeg encoded frames and some audio data into a chunk of h264 and then send it directly as a response to a GET request making it a stream?

This not only would simplify the whole serving multiple webpages thing, but also remove the issues of syncing the audio and video if they are sent separately.

In particular I'm also curious how easy would it be to do on esp32 since it doesn't have a whole bunch of ram and computational power. It would be challenging to find or port large libraries which could help as well, so i guess I would have to code it myself.

I also am not sure if h264 is the best option. I know its supported on most browser out of the box and is using jpeg compression behind the scenes for the frames, but perhaps a simpler format exists which is also widely supported.

So to sum it up: Is h264 a best bet in the provided context? Is combining jpeg and uncompressed mono audio into h264 possible in the provided context? If an answer to either of previous questions is a no, what alternatives do i have if any?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm curious if it would be possible to combine jpeg encoded frames and some audio data into a chunk of h264 and then send it directly as a response to a GET request making it a stream?

H.264 is a video codec.  It doesn't have anything to do with audio.

> I know its supported on most browser out of the box and is using jpeg compression behind the scenes for the frames

No, this isn't true.  H.264 is its own thing.  It's far more powerful than JPEG and is specifically designed for motion, whereas JPEG was not.

You need a few things:

- A video codec, to efficiently handle your frames.  Most of these embedded camera libraries can give you an MJPEG stream.  I'd use that if possible.  I don't think your ESP32 has other video encoding capability, does it?  H.264 is a good choice, but only if you can actually encode it.
- A container format, to aid in streaming your audio and video streams together.  ISOBMFF/MP4 is common, as is WebM/Matroska.

If you're only streaming to a single client (which seems likely given the limited horsepower of the board), and if you have enough capability to do the audio/video encoding, you can generate a WebM stream on the fly that is directly playable in a `<video>` element.  This seems exactly what you are asking for.